# Problems with mysql CREATE TABLE syntax

Tags: mysql

I try to create table in mysql with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE keys (id INT(10), key VARCHAR(100));
```

and it always gives me an error like this:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (id INT(10), key VARCHAR(100))' at line 1`

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both the table name `keys` and the field `key` are reserved in the Mysql namespace. If you choose a different table name (e.g. `keys_tbl`) and rename the second field something like `key_id`, your code will work.

Comment: ... or quote these names with backticks. Of course, not recommended - but it is possible nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

You should be very carefully with table and columns naming, you might face a lot of problems in the future.

I suggest find names that are not [MySQL reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

If you still want to keep the names you should put in in backticks.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE keys (id INT(10), key VARCHAR(100));
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys (id INT(10), key VARCHAR(100))' at line 1

mysql> CREATE TABLE `keys` (id INT(10), `key` VARCHAR(100));
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.97 sec)

mysql> show create table keys;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys' at line 1
mysql>
mysql>
mysql> show create table `keys`;
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                        |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| keys  | CREATE TABLE `keys` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `key` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Note that you have to use backticks when using the table**

Comment: Being forced to use backticks to refer to your tablenames will INCREASE your lifetime project cost beyond reason.  Choose table and column names that are descriptive of their respective content and NOT RESERVED keywords for your DBMS.  our_keys  key_desc might be more descriptive.